# Why is vertical align with flexbox (1:1 copy of MDN example) not working in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I copy the code from the MDN flexbox documentation to test a vertical alignment of a box in a window:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Typical_Use_Cases_of_Flexbox

Why is the box not vertically aligned? I use Google Chrome  63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit), OS Ubuntu 16.04, JavaScript V8 6.3.292.48

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./pers.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                                       initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, its not `align-content` but its `align-items`. Secondly you need to specify height to the parent element so that its contents is positioned in the center. Hope the below snippet works for you.

```css
html, body{
height: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./pers.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Saw it at the same time, got to use `align-content` because of some page saying should use `align-content`.

Comment: `align-content` is same as `align-items` but in place of aligning flex items, it aligns flex lines.

Answer (score -1):

The flexbox container (`.box`) height property needs to be set, the flexbox items (descendants of `.box`) then align vertically. So add

```
height: 100%;
```

to `.box` style. Also, use `align-items` property instead of `align-content`.